# Parsing a file into a map using Elixir; Am I using the Enum.zip function correctly?

Tags: elixir

I am attempting to parse a text file [a query result from somewhere else] into a map.  My issue is I only ever get three items in the map.  there are 30 or so items in the map and an inspect shows that they are parsed.  They look fine as far as I can see...

I have the following module defined in Elixir:

```
 defmodule Statistics do
  
  def read(path) do

      case File.read(path) do
        {:ok, body} ->
           parse_body body

        {:error, reason} ->
          IO.puts(~s(could not open file "#{path}"\n))
          IO.puts(~s("#{:file.format_error(reason)}"\n))
      end
    end


  def parse_lines(lines, keys) do
    Enum.reduce(lines, %{}, fn line, built ->
      [name | fields] = String.split(line, "\t")

      # IO.inspect(fields)

      if Enum.count(keys) == Enum.count(fields) do
        line_data = Enum.zip(keys, fields) |> Enum.into(%{})
        Map.merge(built, %{name => line_data})
      else
        built
      end
    end)
  end

  def parse_body(body) do
    [header | lines] = String.split(body, ~r(\r\n|\r|\n))
    keys = tl String.split(header, "\t")
    parse_lines(lines, keys)
  end

end
```

I also have a text file with with the following content:

```
   Abandon_agent    Abandon_system  answered_greater_than_20    answered_less_than_20   answered_less_than_15   answered_less_than_10   answered_less_than_5    date
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2022-09-29
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2022-10-01
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2022-10-02
0   0   0   0   4   24  9   2022-10-03
0   0   2   0   6   22  23  2022-10-04
2   0   0   0   7   16  21  2022-10-05
1   0   1   0   8   12  35  2022-10-06
0   0   0   2   8   9   29  2022-10-07
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2022-10-08
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2022-10-09
0   0   2   3   3   18  12  2022-10-10
0   0   1   2   5   16  6   2022-10-11
0   0   0   2   6   24  19  2022-10-12
0   0   1   2   3   20  29  2022-10-13
1   0   1   2   2   11  10  2022-10-14
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2022-10-15
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2022-10-16
0   0   1   1   6   17  11  2022-10-17
0   0   1   1   4   16  11  2022-10-18
0   0   0   1   7   18  12  2022-10-19
0   0   1   1   6   21  9   2022-10-20
1   0   0   3   1   20  17  2022-10-21
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2022-10-22
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2022-10-23
0   0   1   1   9   37  15  2022-10-24
0   0   0   1   4   21  14  2022-10-25
1   0   1   2   0   21  12  2022-10-26
0   0   3   2   7   17  13  2022-10-27
0   0   1   0   1   9   27  2022-10-28
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2022-10-29
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2022-10-30
0   0   0   0   4   21  8   2022-10-31
```

Even though an inspect shows the parsed data,
I only ever get this:

```
    %{
  "0" => %{
    "Abandon_system" => "0",
    "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
    "answered_less_than_10" => "21",
    "answered_less_than_15" => "4",
    "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
    "answered_less_than_5" => "8",
    "date" => "2022-10-31"
  },
  "1" => %{
    "Abandon_system" => "0",
    "answered_greater_than_20" => "1",
    "answered_less_than_10" => "21",
    "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
    "answered_less_than_20" => "2",
    "answered_less_than_5" => "12",
    "date" => "2022-10-26"
  },
  "2" => %{
    "Abandon_system" => "0",
    "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
    "answered_less_than_10" => "16",
    "answered_less_than_15" => "7",
    "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
    "answered_less_than_5" => "21",
    "date" => "2022-10-05"
  }
}
```

Just for completeness, the inspect of the [parsed] fields shows this: [all of the data]. Am I using zip wrong?

```
[Statistics]
iex(107)> records = Statistics.read "/home/joe/projects/playland_elixir/statistics/lib/by_date.txt"
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2022-09-29"]
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2022-10-01"]
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2022-10-02"]
["0", "0", "0", "4", "24", "9", "2022-10-03"]
["0", "2", "0", "6", "22", "23", "2022-10-04"]
["0", "0", "0", "7", "16", "21", "2022-10-05"]
["0", "1", "0", "8", "12", "35", "2022-10-06"]
["0", "0", "2", "8", "9", "29", "2022-10-07"]
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2022-10-08"]
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2022-10-09"]
["0", "2", "3", "3", "18", "12", "2022-10-10"]
["0", "1", "2", "5", "16", "6", "2022-10-11"]
["0", "0", "2", "6", "24", "19", "2022-10-12"]
["0", "1", "2", "3", "20", "29", "2022-10-13"]
["0", "1", "2", "2", "11", "10", "2022-10-14"]
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2022-10-15"]
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2022-10-16"]
["0", "1", "1", "6", "17", "11", "2022-10-17"]
["0", "1", "1", "4", "16", "11", "2022-10-18"]
["0", "0", "1", "7", "18", "12", "2022-10-19"]
["0", "1", "1", "6", "21", "9", "2022-10-20"]
["0", "0", "3", "1", "20", "17", "2022-10-21"]
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2022-10-22"]
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2022-10-23"]
["0", "1", "1", "9", "37", "15", "2022-10-24"]
["0", "0", "1", "4", "21", "14", "2022-10-25"]
["0", "1", "2", "0", "21", "12", "2022-10-26"]
["0", "3", "2", "7", "17", "13", "2022-10-27"]
["0", "1", "0", "1", "9", "27", "2022-10-28"]
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2022-10-29"]
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2022-10-30"]
["0", "0", "0", "4", "21", "8", "2022-10-31"]
[]
```

Comment: Side note: check out the `trim: true` option to [`String.split/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3) to avoid the empty last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the first column as a key to a map. In maps, there can only be one of each key. As you only have three unique values (`0`, `1`, `2`) in the first column, only the last occurrence of each survives your `reduce` call.

Here's an example that returns the (key, value) pairs as a tuple, where you can see the duplicate keys that are getting replaced in your code.

```elixir
def parse_lines(lines, keys) do
  Enum.map(lines, fn line ->
    [name | fields] = String.split(line, "\t")
    line_data = Enum.zip(keys, fields) |> Enum.into(%{})
    {name, line_data}
  end)
end
```

Result:

```elixir
[
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "0",
     "date" => "2022-09-29"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "0",
     "date" => "2022-10-01"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "0",
     "date" => "2022-10-02"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "24",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "4",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "9",
     "date" => "2022-10-03"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "2",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "22",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "6",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "23",
     "date" => "2022-10-04"
   }},
  {"2",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "16",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "7",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "21",
     "date" => "2022-10-05"
   }},
  {"1",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "12",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "8",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "35",
     "date" => "2022-10-06"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "9",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "8",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "2",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "29",
     "date" => "2022-10-07"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "0",
     "date" => "2022-10-08"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "0",
     "date" => "2022-10-09"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "2",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "18",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "3",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "3",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "12",
     "date" => "2022-10-10"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "16",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "5",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "2",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "6",
     "date" => "2022-10-11"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "24",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "6",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "2",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "19",
     "date" => "2022-10-12"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "20",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "3",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "2",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "29",
     "date" => "2022-10-13"
   }},
  {"1",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "11",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "2",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "2",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "10",
     "date" => "2022-10-14"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "0",
     "date" => "2022-10-15"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "0",
     "date" => "2022-10-16"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "17",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "6",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "11",
     "date" => "2022-10-17"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "16",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "4",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "11",
     "date" => "2022-10-18"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "18",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "7",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "12",
     "date" => "2022-10-19"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "21",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "6",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "9",
     "date" => "2022-10-20"
   }},
  {"1",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "20",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "3",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "17",
     "date" => "2022-10-21"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "0",
     "date" => "2022-10-22"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "0",
     "date" => "2022-10-23"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "37",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "9",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "15",
     "date" => "2022-10-24"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "21",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "4",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "14",
     "date" => "2022-10-25"
   }},
  {"1",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "21",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "2",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "12",
     "date" => "2022-10-26"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "3",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "17",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "7",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "2",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "13",
     "date" => "2022-10-27"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "9",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "1",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "27",
     "date" => "2022-10-28"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "0",
     "date" => "2022-10-29"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "0",
     "date" => "2022-10-30"
   }},
  {"0",
   %{
     "Abandon_system" => "0",
     "answered_greater_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_10" => "21",
     "answered_less_than_15" => "4",
     "answered_less_than_20" => "0",
     "answered_less_than_5" => "8",
     "date" => "2022-10-31"
   }}
]
```